ASP.NET Core MVC 8 DateTime Model Validation always invalid
I'm working on a ASP.NET Core MVC 8 migration project from ASP.NET Core 3.1 version.
Some packages are still on version 3.1:

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design

Even though some packages are in different versions project compiles well and is able to run.
It seems to have some retro-compatibility
I'm having an issue with a DateTime property model validation always giving an invalid date. Even though while I'm debugging view model object has the DateTime value set, and I try to rerun the model validation manually the model state still is invalid.
I have a view page with a date picker input field like the following:
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}",
         new { @class = "btn", type = "date", @Value = Model?.Date })

My view model has a DateTime attribute as follows:
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
[RegularExpression(@"{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Date")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }

I would appreciate any other suggestion.
I've tried some suggestions from other SO questions with no success:

Format date within View in ASP.NET Core MVC
Why my DateTime ModelState is invalid?

I've tried changing the validation attributes for other regular expressions (like: [RegularExpression(@"^\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid date format")] ), I also tried changing the property type to string so it could be "easier" to handle it. I've tried removing the regular expression and letting only the DataType annotation... but I'm still having the validation error.
Finally I was expecting have the Model State as valid. What am I doing wrongly?

You're using type = "date", which allows values in "yyyy-MM-dd" format only. You do not get a choice in the date format when using type="date". This is mentioned in a comment on one of the questions mentioned.

Well, I've already tried keeping the format as "yyyy-MM-dd" in the view model validation attribute and also in the view page which is fine to me because the UI keeps the format as "MM/dd/yyyy". Is your suggestion remove any date format string from those?

If you want to keep using type="date", I'd remove that RegularExpression attribute and keep the (internal) format as "yyyy-MM-dd". The UI will show the date according to the user's regional settings (in most browsers).

I removed the RegularExpression attribute, but the debugger doesn't reach the Controller action anymore it  simply redirects to the error page when I click on the action button.

Just another curious thing, while debugging after being redirected to the project's default error page if use the "browser back feature" the debug triggers in the controller with the last input data and no model state error is shown.

I found out my issue was related to another portion of the project.
The DateTime validation was resolved implementing the exact the same suggestion as in the comment
I've removed the Regular Expression and kept the DataType[(DataType.Date)] annotation and also removed the date string format from the .cshmtl View.
Thanks for the comment!
